# #define directive clarification

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Sorry if this is a a bad question but . . .

I want to create a shortcut to my UIColor that looks like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0f/255.0f) green:(201.0f/255.0f) blue:(234.0f/255.0f) alpha:1]
```

Can I use a #define for that somehow so that I can just type in some shortcut? I've tried but I think my notation may be off . . .

If a #define is only for constants or for some reason doesn't apply in this situation, are there any other ways to shortcut that method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#define is just a glorified text replacement system. If you define something like this:

```
#define key value
```

then the preprocessor will replace every occurrence of `key`with `value` even before the compiler can do anything. So it doesn't really matter what you define. You can use anything as your value, so you could do something like

```
#define kMyColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0f/255.0f) green:(201.0f/255.0f) blue:(234.0f/255.0f) alpha:1]
```

But in this case you probably should use a static constant variable:

```
static const UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0f/255.0f) green:(201.0f/255.0f) blue:(234.0f/255.0f) alpha:1];
```

Comment: `myColor` will have to be assigned to inside of a method or function, but that's definitely better than having a define that looks like a constant but is actually a call.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define RGBA(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r) green:(g) blue:(b) alpha:(a)]
```

Intead using:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0f/255.0f) green:(201.0f/255.0f) blue:(234.0f/255.0f) alpha:1]
```

Use this:

```
RGBA(0.35,0.79,0.92,1)
```

Take a look at this tutorial:
[UIColor Shortcuts](http://imadjine.com/blog/2011/09/26/uicolor-shortcuts/).

Answer (score 4):

By your question's text it is not really clear, what you want to shortcut — one single color, the creation of RGBA colors with values `[0..255]`?

DrummerB answered the first, Justin Boo the second.

I want to propose a solution, that fits for both:

Create a category, that can cover both

- `[UIColor colorWith255ValuesWithRed: 128 green: 35 blue: 40 alpha:255]`, that wraps the method, you are using now
- create a UIColor class method, that stores UIColor objects in a static NSMutableDictionary with their names and the counter part, you would call like `[UIColor registeredColorWithName:@"activeForegroundColor"]`

I wrote a sample code for the color register idea:

**UIColor+Register.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Register)
+(void)registerColor:(UIColor *)color 
             forName:(NSString *)name;

+(UIColor *)registeredColorForName:(NSString *)name;

+(void)unregisterColorForName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

**UIColor+Register.m**

```
#import "UIColor+Register.h"

@interface UIColor (RegisterPrivate)
+(NSMutableDictionary *)colorRegister;
@end

@implementation UIColor (RegisterPrivate)
+(NSMutableDictionary *)colorRegister
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSMutableDictionary *register_;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        register_ = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    });
    return register_;
}
@end


@implementation UIColor (Register)

+(void)registerColor:(UIColor *)color 
             forName:(NSString *)name
{
    [[self colorRegister] setObject:color forKey:name];
}

+(UIColor *)registeredColorForName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [[self colorRegister] objectForKey:name];
}

+(void)unregisterColorForName:(NSString *)name
{
    [[self colorRegister] removeObjectForKey:name];
}

@end
```

**Usage:**
*register*

```
[UIColor registerColor:[UIColor redColor] forName:@"activeColor"];
[UIColor registerColor:[UIColor grayColor] forName:@"passiveColor"];
```

*access*

```
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor registeredColorForName:@"passiveColor"]];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor registeredColorForName:@"activeColor"]];
```

*unregister*

```
[UIColor unregisterColorForName:@"activeColor"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a category on UIColor and define a new class method (like blackColor, whiteColor etc). This way your code at least fits in with the existing style.

```
+(UIColor*)myColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0f/255.0f) green:(201.0f/255.0f) blue:(234.0f/255.0f) alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: please refer to my answer for a similar but more dynamic approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's a define for HEX RGB if you'd like:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Usage:

```
UIColor *color = UIColorFromRGB(0xe8e600); //0xe8e600 hex representation...
```